# When will Endnote X4 for Mac be compatible with Word for Mac 2011?

Tags: software, ms-office

In the meantime, how can one manage?

Answer (score 1):

According to [their website](http://www.endnote.com/enword2k7.asp):

> EndNote X4 is not compatible with Word 2011. The compatibility of Word 2011 with EndNote X4 will be addressed in a free update. Please register your software to be informed when EndNote X4 is compatible with Word 2011.

On their message board, [this message](http://community.thomsonreuters.com/t5/EndNote-General/Currently-no-support-in-Endnote-X4-for-Office-2011-for-Mac/m-p/12960#M4131) says:

> The schedule has changed since then so I cannot provide a firm ETA, other than we're now targeting the first quarter of 2011.

From the later comments in that thread (and other threads [in their forum](http://community.thomsonreuters.com/t5/EndNote-General/bd-p/en-general)), there appear to be a *lot* of unhappy customers.

Your other options appear to be:

- [Use X4 with MS Word 2008](http://www.endnote.com/support/en_wpchart_mac.asp) (and thankfully, you can run 2008 and 2011 apps at the same time)
- [Use X4 with Pages '09](http://www.endnote.com/support/en_wpchart_mac.asp)
- [Use X3 with MS Word 2011](http://www.macintouch.com/readerreports/office2011/topic4918.html#item.122419)
- [Apply to beta test](http://www.endnote.com/testing/) the Word 2011 version of X4
- Don't use Endnote; instead just use [Word 2011's built-in tools](http://community.thomsonreuters.com/t5/EndNote-General/Currently-no-support-in-Endnote-X4-for-Office-2011-for-Mac/m-p/13471#M4293)